# Sort table rows based on background-color using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

This is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fy050ctb/3/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:blue;color:white">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:pink;color:white">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:blue;color:white">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:green;color:white">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:pink;color:white">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:green;color:white">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do i rearrange the html table rows based on color? I want to group html table rows based on the background color of the rows.

Comment: What is your use case exactly? When do you want your rows to rearrange?

Comment: Your html code is not that well formed though. Too many div closing tags.

Comment: Thanks.. I have updated the fiddle..

Comment: 1) What have you tried so far? 2) On its own, color is a fragile way to represent data.

Comment: I wanted to rearrange the HTML table rows so that it should group by the background color, as shown in my fiddle

Comment: am I right in assuming that the 2nd table where you have your arranged rows will not be created (i.e. hardcoded). and you just created it for demo purposes

Comment: yes... 2nd table is what i want.. 1st table is what is now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sorting array of `tr` elements. You can get `backgroud-color` of element in function of sort and set arrangement of every element.

```js
$("table tr").sort(function (a, b){
    return $("div", b).css("background") < $("div", a).css("background") ? 1 : -1;    
}).appendTo('table');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:blue">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:pink">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:blue">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:green">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:pink">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="background:green">hello</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed your question, I think you want to differentiate each tr by there color, adding html, style and script for you here.

Here is the Html

```
 <table>
     </tbody>
        <tr><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>123</td></tr>
     </table>
```

Do add this script, by this function all your tr will have unique classes. you can add there background colors etc style on the base of class

```
 <script>
 // please do add jQuery file to prevent error
 function adddClass() {
      for(i=1; i<=6; i++) {
          alert("");
          jQuery('table tr:nth-child('+ i +')').addClass("color"+i);
      }
  }
  adddClass();
  </script>
```

Here is the style for background color of each table row tr

```
<style>
.color1{background-color:orange;}
.color2{background-color:teal;}
.color3{background-color:red;}
.color4{background-color:#717171;}
.color5{background-color:khaki;}
.color6{background-color:lightgray;}
tr, table, body{width:100%;}
</style>
```

Hope this will help, Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in javascript.

1. Initiate an empty js object like this `var colorRowmap = {}`
2. Loop through all elements(tr elements) of table and get colorName from each tr. And if that color does not exist as a key of colorRowMap object do `colorRowMap[colorName] = [currentTableRow]` else do `colorRowMap[colorName] = colorRowMap[colorName].push(currentTableRow)`
3. Empty the table.
4. Loop through all keys of colorRowMap and push the tr roows to table.

Done. :)